# Why do I keep getting argument of type 'method' is not iterable?

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

I am trying to make a chess program, but cannot get past a section that keeps returning an error. I've checked the code over and cannot find what's wrong with it. It keeps saying 'argument of type 'method' is not iterable'. Online says it's due to a parenthesis error, but I can't find where.

```
if len(userClick)==2: # if its player click number 2
    move = chessEngine.Move(userClick[0],userClick[1],SoG.board)
    print(move.chessNotation())
    if move in legalMoves: # this is where the error occurs
        SoG.makingMove(move)
        moveMade = True
    selectedSquare = () # reset square selected
    userClick = [] # reset user clicks
```

I have some of the other code here,

```
def legalMoves(self): # possible moves
    return self.possibleMoves()

def possibleMoves(self):
    moves = [] #Move((6,4),(4,4),self.board)
    for r in range(len(self.board)): # number of rows
        for c in range(len(self.board[r])): # number of columns in a row
            colourOfTurn = self.board[r][c][0]
            if (colourOfTurn == 'b' and not self.whiteMove) and (colourOfTurn == 'w' and self.whiteMove):
                piece = self.board[r][c][1]
                if piece == 'P': # pawns
                    self.pawnMoves(r,c,moves)
                elif piece == 'R': # rooks
                    self.rookMoves(r,c,moves)
                #elif piece == 'N': # knights
                 #   self.knightMoves(r,c,moves)
                #elif piece == 'B': # bishop
                 #   self.bishopMoves(r,c,moves)
                #elif piece == 'Q': # queen
                 #   self.queenMoves(r,c,moves)
                #elif piece == 'K': # king
                 #   self.kingMoves(r,c,moves)
    return moves
```

Comment: `legalMoves` seems to be a method but there is no class and it is not called in the context of an instance. Please provide a minimal **reproducible** example!

Comment: As a side note - why do you have `legalMoves()` method which is just a wrapper and is used only to call `possibleMoves()`? Even the comment says `# possible moves`

Comment: @buran It's not finished yet. in order to validate chess, I need to know all possible moves before finding legal moves. Once I've completed possible moves I'll move to legal moves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `legalMoves` with parenthesis, like this:

`if move in legalMoves():`